# Subclassing Sequential() keras-model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I wanted to subclass a sequential model in order to be able to write a custom `call()` and handle named inputs. However, I got, for me, some unexpected behavior already for very minor changes to the `__init__` function. If I try to add a new member to my subclass and initialize it after calling `super().__init__()` the model fails to build automatically.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Activation, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten
import tensorflow as tf
class Sequential2(Sequential):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Sequential2, self).__init__()
        self.custom_member = []

    def get_my_custom_member(self):
        return self.custom_member

model = Sequential2()

if tf.keras.backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (1, 28, 28)
else:
    assert tf.keras.backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_last'
    input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

layers = [Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape)]

for layer in layers:
    model.add(layer)

model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.summary()
```

fails with output: `` ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or calling `fit()` with some data, or specify an `input_shape` argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build. ``

However if `self.custom_member = []` is left out it works as expected.

What am I missing here? (tested with Tensorflow 1.14)

Comment: Even do not work with tf 2.2 (I ve got similar issue). [Pytorch  background]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed in `TF 2.2`. You can refer working code as shown below

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Activation, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

class Sequential2(Sequential):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Sequential2, self).__init__()
        self.custom_member = []

    def get_my_custom_member(self):
        return self.custom_member

model = Sequential2()

if tf.keras.backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (1, 28, 28)
else:
    assert tf.keras.backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_last'
    input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

layers = [Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape)]

for layer in layers:
    model.add(layer)

model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.summary()
```

Output:

```
2.2.0
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 26, 26, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 26, 26, 10)        330       
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 26, 26, 10)        0         
=================================================================
Total params: 650
Trainable params: 650
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```